# How to convert a JSON's file tree structure into a single line?

Tags: conversion, json

I have a JSON file as below

```
{
    "Foo": "ABC",
    "Bar": "20090101100000",
    "Quux": {
        "QuuxId": 1234,
        "QuuxName": "Sam"
    }
}
```

I want to convert it to the below

```
{"Foo":"ABC","Bar":"20090101100000","Quux":{"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"}}
```

I tried to remove '\n', '\t', and ' ' characters; but I am not getting in the needed format. How can I convert it?

Answer (score 12):

The safest way would be to use a JSON parser, otherwise, you technically run the risk of modifying data.

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq -c . file.json
{"Foo":"ABC","Bar":"20090101100000","Quux":{"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"}}
```

The `-c` flag to `jq` is the short version of the `--compact-output` flag and will prompt `jq` to generate the most compact output possible.  The dot is a simple pass-through filter that won't modify any of the data.

Note that the two ways of representing the JSON document are equivalent since any whitespace between the keys and values are irrelevant.  A JSON parser would read either format (or anything in-between) with no issues.

Comment: Any trick how to escape all the quotes? Except for doing it manually? :-)

Comment: @jreisinger Why would you want to escape the quotes?

Comment: I want to feed the single line JSON to `aws` CLI tool and have shell (bash) variables in the JSON.

Comment: @jreisinger `jq -n --arg var "$variable" '{ "mykey": $var }'`. This would properly create a JSON document where the shell variable `$variable` is inserted as a value (including any necessary encoding). If the value in `$variable` is already a JSON document, use `--argjson` in place of `--arg`.

Comment: @jreisinger If that does not solve it, please consider asking a new question (and then probably have it closed as a duplicate, because I'm sure I've answered this one before).